How to search for potentially applicable methods for a method reference in Java?
The questions I asked a few days ago were too chaotic, so I want to express my meaning more clearly here.
First, let's look at an example：
interface Fun<T,R> { R apply(T arg); } 
    class C { 
    int size() { return 0; } 
    static int size(Object arg) { return 0; } 
    void test() { 
        Fun<C, Integer> f1 = C::size; 
 
    } 
}

I tried to analyze this code to see what the method invocation referred to by the method reference should be.
According to JLS 15.13.1:
Apparently, the type to be searched is the class type C.
And then:

• Second, given a targeted function type with n parameters, a set of
potentially applicable methods is identified:

If the method
reference expression has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments]
Identifier, then the potentially applicable methods are:

the member
methods of the type to search that would be potentially applicable
(§15.12.2.1) for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity
n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as
the method reference expression; plus
the member methods of the type
to search that would be potentially applicable for a method invocation
which names Identifier, has arity n-1, has type arguments
TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference
expression.




According to the JLS, now assume there is a method invocation, "names Identifier, has arity n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression", and then determine whether this assumed method invocation is potentially applicable with the two member methods appearing in class C.
They have the same name and the same arity.
And, because of the sentence "and appears in the same class as the method reference expression",the class in which the method invocation occurs is determined so as to make the judgment of the sentence "The member is accessible (§6.6) to the class or interface in which the method invocation appears."(15.12.2.1)
However, what about compatibility? It doesn't provide the argument types of the assumed method invocation.
How to make a judgment on

" If the member is a fixed arity method with arity n, the arity of the
method invocation is equal to =n, and for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n), the i'th
argument of the method invocation is potentially compatible, as
defined below, with the type of the i'th parameter of the method."

?(15.12.2.1)
In other words, not just static int size(Object arg). If I also have
static int size(String arg), and so on with parameters of any type, are they also necessarily potentially applicable member methods(Because it has nothing to do with the types of parameters and arguments.)?
Thank you for reading and answering.
I don't think my question is similar to this one.If only judging the potential applicability of member methods and method invocations, the specifications are clearly written.Method references are involved here. According to the specification, my understanding is that a member method will be compared with a assumed invocation.However, for this assumed invocation, the information provided by the specification seems to be insufficient.

@Marce Puente No. According to the specification, that is a condition for the applicability of a method, rather than potential applicability. It seems that the requirements for arguments and parameters are very loose regarding potential applicability.

@user24723440 it seems that you forgot to add the example. Your post starts with First, let's look at an example：, but there is no example. For me this makes it harder to understand what you struggle with.

... but yes, all those methods int size(somearg) are potentially applicable and then the following sentence from 15.13. Method Reference Expressions applies: When more than one member method of a type has the same name, or when a class has more than one constructor, the appropriate method or constructor is selected based on the functional interface type targeted by the method reference expression, as specified in §15.13.1.

@Thomas Kläger Strange. I remember that I added examples...

@Thomas Kläger My question is that when judging whether the member methods in class C are potentially applicable, it should be compared with an assumed method invocation, as stated in the JLS. However, the specification doesn't explain the argument types of this assumed method invocation. And when judging whether the member methods are potentially applicable, we need to judge whether the types of parameters and arguments are potentially compatible. How can this be judged?

It seems that your missed the final step of the resolution process. See my anwer for details.

Given this declaration:
interface Fun<T,R> { R apply(T arg); } 

class C { 
    int size() { return 0; } 
    static int size(Object arg) { return 0; }
    static int size(String arg) { return arg.length(); }

    void test() { 
        Fun<C, Integer> f1 = C::size; 
    } 
}

the 15.13.1. Compile-Time Declaration of a Method Reference describes a three step process to determine the method to reference:


First, a type to search is determined

If the method reference expression has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, the type to search is the result of capture conversion (§5.1.10) applied to ReferenceType.




The method reference expression C::size has this form and therefore the type to search is C.


Second, given a targeted function type with n parameters, a set of potentially applicable methods is identified:

If the method reference expression has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, then the potentially applicable methods are:

the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially applicable (§15.12.2.1) for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression; plus
the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially applicable for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity n-1, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression.






The targeted function type Fun<C, Integer> has one parameter. This step accordingly finds 3 potentially applicable functions:
    int size() { return 0; } 
    static int size(Object arg) { return 0; }
    static int size(String arg) { return arg.length(); }

This step explicity only uses the name, the arity and the type arguments as search criteria, as written in this step and also as written in the linked 15.12.2.1. Identify Potentially Applicable Methods.
Selecting the actual method according to the arguments happens according to §15.12.2.2 through §15.12.2.5, but the spec here mentions explicitly that this is done as part of the following last step.
Then there is this last step (that you seem to miss or ignore):


Finally, if there are no potentially applicable methods, then there is no compile-time declaration.
Otherwise, given a targeted function type with parameter types P1, ..., Pn and a set of potentially applicable methods, the compile-time declaration is selected as follows:

If the method reference expression has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, then two searches for a most specific applicable method are performed. Each search is as specified in §15.12.2.2 through §15.12.2.5, with the clarifications below. Each search produces a set of applicable methods and, possibly, designates a most specific method of the set. In the case of an error as specified in §15.12.2.4, the set of applicable methods is empty. In the case of an error as specified in §15.12.2.5, there is no most specific method.
(A) In the first search, the method reference is treated as if it were an invocation with argument expressions of types P1, ..., Pn. Type arguments, if any, are given by the method reference expression.
(B) In the second search, if P1, ..., Pn is not empty and P1 is a subtype of ReferenceType, then the method reference expression is treated as if it were a method invocation expression with argument expressions of types P2, ..., Pn. If ReferenceType is a raw type, and there exists a parameterization of this type, G<...>, that is a supertype of P1, the type to search is the result of capture conversion (§5.1.10) applied to G<...>; otherwise, the type to search is the same as the type of the first search. Type arguments, if any, are given by the method reference expression.
(C) If the first search produces a most specific method that is static, and the set of applicable methods produced by the second search contains no non-static methods, then the compile-time declaration is the most specific method of the first search.
(D) Otherwise, if the set of applicable methods produced by the first search contains no static methods, and the second search produces a most specific method that is non-static, then the compile-time declaration is the most specific method of the second search.
(E) Otherwise, there is no compile-time declaration.





(I've added markers A to E for reference in the following explanation)
The targeted function type Fun<C, Integer> has one parameter of type C.
(A) The first search for a most specific applicable method finds the static method static int size(Object arg).
(B) The second search for a most specific applicable method finds instance method int size().
(C) Since the first search produces a most specific method that is static, but the set of applicable methods produced by the second search contains non-static methods, the first case does not apply.
(D) Since the set of applicable methods produced by the first search contains static methods, so this case also does not apply.
(E) is the fallback case: the resolution is ambiguous and results in a compile error.

Note that this same five steps 15.12.2.1. Identify Potentially Applicable Methods through §15.12.2.5 also happen in a normal method invocation: they first search for potentially applicable methods according to the method name, arity and type arguments and only after that take the actual argument expressions into account.

Thank you, but I don't think I missed the last step. Or rather, that wasn't my intention.
Let's analyze the second step carefully instead of just glossing over it.

The potentially applicable regulations are for an invocation and a method. Then let's look at the second step of your citation. The second step presents a hypothetical (non-existent in reality) method invocation. According to C::size, we can obtain that the "Identifier" is size,  "n" is 1, and "TypeArguments" do not exist.So now we have a hypothetical invocation:size(a);

But do they satisfy the "potentially applicable" rule just because the number of arguments in the invocation is the same as the number of parameters of the method? No. The rule also requires that their parameters and arguments be "potentially compatible". But we don't know the type of the arguments of the invocation at all, because the specification doesn't mention it.

@user24723440 the specification is clear to the point: in step two potentially applicable methods are selected according to the methods name, arity and type arguments (as described in that step and also in the spec §15.12.2.1). The types of (potential) arguments expressions only play a role in that final step, as described in that step of the spec and in §15.12.2.2 through §15.12.2.5 which are only mentioned in that final step)
